# How to get the constant value from a trait?

Tags: scala, constants, traits

I defined a trait `RequireLogin` with a constant:

```
trait RequireLogin {
    val message = "you should login"
    if(sessionUser.isEmpty) {
        Global.error(message)
        throw new RedirectException("/login", message);
    }
}
```

Now in my test, I created an object with this trait, and test if the `Global.error()` is equal to `RequireLogin.message`.

```
try {
    new Object with RequireLogin
} catch {
    case _: RedirectException =>
}
Global.error should be === RequireLogin.message // !!! can't be compiled
```

But it can't be compiled.

Is there any way to get the constant from a trait? Or how to refactor my code to make it better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What comes to mind is to define a companion object holding the constant:

```
object RequireLogin {
    val message = "you should login"
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I don't think you'll be able to get the value out of the trait itself without using reflection.